# Elixir: How to send body parameters using hackney

Tags: erlang, elixir

I am making a `post` request in elixir using [hackney](https://github.com/benoitc/hackney), which appears to be functioning properly, but on the receiving service the body is empty.

Is there a hackney option that I am missing? I've tried sending the body as a charlist as well as a native string.

```
msg = Jason.encode!(%{message: "hello"})

{:ok, 200, _, body} = :hackney.post(
  "http://localhost:2002/api/some/endpoint",
  [
    {'Content-Type', 'application/json'}
  ],
  msg,
  [:with_body]
)

IO.inspect(Jason.decode!(body), label: "response")
# => {:ok, "ok"}
```

Comment: *I've tried sending the body as a charlist as well as a native string.*--If you forget that elixir has single quoted strings, you would probably be better off.  A single quoted string is a shortcut for creating a list of integers, and a server has no idea what a list of integers is.  Now, a *sequence* of integers is how a string  is transmitted "over the wire", but there are no commas separating those integers, and there are no brackets surrounding the outside of those integers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sent the body for me, but it appears to want `"application/json"` as a binary instead of a charlist. When I did a charlist I got a numeric content type header.

It's possible your server would get that content type and handle the request body in such a way it doesn't appear to be getting sent.

This is what I ended up with (I also changed the header name to a lowercase binary for consistency, but it doesn't seem necessary)

```rb
:hackney.post("http://localhost:2002/api/some/endpoint", [{"content-type", "application/json"}], msg, [:with_body])
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be the use of double quoted strings in elixir.

This means all strings that are passed as parameters should probably be enclosed in double quotes and not single quotes, when they are created. Or be checked and probably converted to string type before sending them.

This **applies to any string parameters** the request might have, and also to the header:

```
{"Content-Type", "application/json"}
```

instead of:

```
{'Content-Type', 'application/json'}
```

From the documentation:

https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.13.1/String.html

**Strings** in Elixir are UTF-8 encoded binaries.

Strings in Elixir are a sequence of Unicode characters, typically written between double quoted strings, such as "hello".

**Charlists on the other hand:**

https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/binaries-strings-and-char-lists.html#charlists

A charlist is a **list of integers** where all the integers are valid code points. In practice, you will not come across them often, except perhaps when interfacing with Erlang, in particular when using older libraries that do not accept binaries as arguments.

Whereas strings (i.e. binaries) are created using double-quotes, charlists are created with **single-quoted literals**.

Instead of containing bytes, a charlist contains integer code points. However, the list is printed in single-quotes if all code points are within the ASCII range.